# Pls how do I create a nested array in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ether

I was trying to create a contract that has multiple rooms, in each room there would be some amount of players. Pls how do I acheive this? This is my approach but it's not working. I am unable to return the mapped array also.

```
contract TheGame {
    uint256 totalRoom;

    struct Room {
        address player;
        uint256 amount;
    }
    Room[] public room;

    mapping(uint256 => Room[]) public eachRoomNumberToEachRoom;

    function createRoom(uint256 _amount) public {
        room.push(Room({
            player: msg.sender,
            amount: _amount
        }));
        totalRoom += 1;
        eachRoomNumberToEachRoom[totalRoom] = room;
    }

    function getEachRoom(uint256 _index) public view returns () {
        return eachRoomNumberToEachRoom[totalRoom][_index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [NESTED_ARRAYS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED](https://github.com/willitscale/learning-solidity/blob/master/support/NESTED_ARRAYS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.MD), you will valuable information.

Comment: I don't get most of the thing clearly tough, thanks you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the return statement when expecting the function that returns a value, so your `getEachRoom` function needs to specify that it's returning a `Room` object that is stored in the memory. So the `getEachRoom` should look like this:

```
    function getEachRoom(uint256 _index) public view returns (Room memory) {
        return eachRoomNumberToEachRoom[totalRoom][_index];
    }
```